# arduino pro mini A4, A5 pin issues

Tags: arduino

I am a arduino beginner, I am working on a project with Arduino Pro Mini, ChronoDot RTC and Adafruit 1604 10DOF. Both ChronoDot RTC and Adafruit 1604 need to use A4, A5 pins on the Pro Mini, so how should i make them work together?

Comment: Might fit better on Arduino.Stackexchange.com but I see you've got quite a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A4 A5 are for I2C communications, which supports many devices sharing same line. So you can connect both of your modules to those pins.

Comment: Thanks, I found the document right after i posted this.